# Hadoop distributed cache archive unarchiving in working directory

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I’m sending an archive to distributed cache via `–Dmapred.cache.archives=hdfs://host:port/path/archive.zip#foldername –D.mapred.create.symlink=yes` and it creates a new folder in the working directory and unarchives the files there. The problem is I need those files in the working directory and I’ve already tried using `.` and `./` as folder name as well as sending an empty one. Any ideas on how to solve this except for moving the files explicitly in my Java code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the specific need for the files to be in the working directory (so i can understand, and suggest some alternatives).

Anyway, it looks like archives in the distributed cache will always be unpacked to a directory so i don't think you can resolve this using archives - however, depending on the number of files you wish to place in the working directory, you can use files in the DistributedCache.

For example, using the GenericOptionsParser parameters you can specify files and folders to include which are then available in the working directory:

```
public static class DistCacheMapper extends
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, NullWritable, NullWritable> {
    @Override
    public void run(Context context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();

        System.err.println("Local Files:");
        listFiles(new File("."), "");
    }

    private void listFiles(File dir, String ident) {
        for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
            System.out.println(ident + (f.isDirectory() ? "d" : "-") + "\t"
                    + f.getName());
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                listFiles(f, ident + "  ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For example with `hadoop jar myjar.jar -files pom.xml,.project,.classpath,src dummy.txt` gives the following on stderr (which you can see has taken the src folder):

```
-   .classpath
-   .project
d   tmp
-   pom.xml
d   src
  d test
    d   resources
    d   java
  d main
    d   resources
    d   java
      d csw
        d   sandbox
          - DistCacheJob.java
          - .DistCacheJob.java.crc
-   job.jar
-   .job.jar.crc
```

So the long and the short of it is you're going to have to list all the files you want in the working directory in the Dist Cache files, and subdirectories can be listed as either archives, or using files too.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I'm aware of most of the alternatives I can use but I just found using an archive was most efficient in terms of size and was the easiest to maintain (as in i could just add more files to it without changing anything else)